# How to allow overflow only for dropdown menus?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to have a dropdown menu as part of my nav bar on my page, but I don't want the buttons to overflow when the screen gets too small.

Currently I have the overflow property set to hidden because it stops the log in and sign up buttons on the right hand side of the nav menu from overflowing when the screen becomes too small and they get close to the other 2 buttons.

If I set the nav bar overflow property to hidden then it hides my dropdown menu. How can I achieve both goals? I've included the current html and css.

```css
    .header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
        padding: 0 20px;
        background-color: white;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden ;
    }
    .topnav{
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100vh / 10);
        background-color: #2B78E4;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden ;
        /*justify-content: space-between;*/
    }
    .topnav a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
        font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    }
    .helmet-logo {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    }
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: #fff1f1;
        color: Black;
        padding: 8px 16px;
    }
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        font-style: inherit;
    }
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        min-width: 160px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 3;
    }
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
    }
    .nav-btn{
        background-color: #fff1f1;
        color: Black;
        padding: 8px 16px;
    }
    #login-btn{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    #signUp-btn{
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
    #login-btn, #signUp-btn {
        float: right;
    }

    #nav-teams{
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Sign Up</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <header>
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href = index.html>
                <img src="images/fb-helmet.png" alt="Logo" class = "helmet-logo">
            </a>

            <div class="teams-btn" id="nav-teams">
                <button class="nav-btn" ><a href="Teams.html">Teams</a></button>
            </div>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Seasons
                    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="Seasons.html">2022</a>
                    <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2021">2021</a>
                    <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2020">2020</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="login-btn">
                <button class = "nav-btn" ><a href="SignIn.html">Log In</a></button>
            </div>

            <div id="signUp-btn">
                <button class="nav-btn" ><a href ="Signup.html">Sign Up</a></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <body>
    
    </body>
    <footer>
       
    </footer>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is where media queries and responsive design come in. You want one layout for a larger screen and a different one for smaller screens. Simply hiding content on smaller screens is unnecessary and quite suboptimal.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting into trouble with overflow because you have not fully thought through your design, especially the mobile design. It’s good practice to do your [small screen design first](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/topics/mobile-first), because it is the most constrained. It’s much easier to adjust a mobile design for desktop than it is to adjust a desktop design for mobile.

So, let’s start by developing the mobile design. We’d probably want the logo and the authentication buttons in the top row, then the navigation buttons in the second row, something like this:

[image: screen shot of suggested mobile design]

On desktop, we have room for everything in one row:

[image: screen shot of suggested desktop design]

So, how to implement this? You’re already using flexbox to implement your navigation bar. Perfect. Did you know that within flex containers you can change the display [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) of the flex items? In this case, that’s useful for changing the sequence of the button groups. In your HTML, put the buttons in the order for the mobile view, so:

1. Logo
2. Authentication buttons
3. Navigation buttons

Then in CSS, use a `@media (min-width: ___px)` rule to make your adjustments for wider screens, including setting an [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) on the authentication buttons to move them to the end of the order. Here is a snippet to demonstrate. When running it, make sure you use the **full page** link.

```css
body {
  margin: 0 10vw 1em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

nav {
  background-color: #2B78E4;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0 -10vw;
}

button, a.button {
  background-color: #fff1f1;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.nav-buttons, .auth-buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-buttons {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 3;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  display: block;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover button {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.spacer {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {

  nav {
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .nav-buttons {
    margin-left: 0;
  }

  .auth-buttons {
    order: 1;
  }

  .spacer {
    display: initial;
    flex: 1;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css">

<nav class="topnav">

  <a href=index.html><img src="https://picsum.photos/100" alt="Logo" class="logo"></a>

  <div class="auth-buttons">
    <a class="button" href="SignIn.html">Log In</a>
    <a class="button" href="Signup.html">Sign Up</a>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-buttons">
    <a class="button" href="Teams.html">Teams</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button>Seasons
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="Seasons.html">2022</a>
            <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2021">2021</a>
            <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2020">2020</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  
</nav>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc laoreet ipsum ac volutpat varius. Mauris vel ultrices leo. Praesent placerat quis lectus in efficitur. Etiam sit amet mollis sapien. Nam vel tortor sed nisl aliquet sollicitudin. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam consectetur, elit sed rhoncus sagittis, diam lacus cursus nibh, in vulputate justo purus ut nibh.
</p>
<p>
Cras mattis libero arcu, non pretium massa blandit quis. Sed in scelerisque turpis. Nulla facilisi. Maecenas facilisis tortor id dui blandit, id tempor dui vulputate. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec vitae ultrices massa. Suspendisse ut condimentum nibh. In erat nulla, facilisis vitae ipsum et, rhoncus lacinia magna. Donec blandit, lectus sit amet interdum convallis, justo est hendrerit nisi, et lacinia massa mi in mi. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
</p>
<p>
Cras fermentum risus vel lorem varius interdum. In pellentesque ligula lacus, vitae sollicitudin purus luctus in. Maecenas accumsan purus ut felis finibus, in tincidunt dui placerat. Etiam eget tristique neque, vitae dignissim ante. Vestibulum eget iaculis sapien. Nunc ornare auctor hendrerit. Vestibulum dui metus, semper at convallis vel, scelerisque semper lectus. Aliquam nec convallis turpis. Nullam in purus eget dolor suscipit imperdiet ut vestibulum magna. Nam ut dui felis.
</p>
<p>
Pellentesque interdum urna ac nisl tincidunt malesuada. Maecenas porttitor interdum dapibus. Aliquam sollicitudin erat a mi interdum, in lobortis diam tristique. Mauris eu lorem id quam interdum gravida. Vivamus eu dui placerat, consectetur orci eu, hendrerit ipsum. Integer quis tincidunt diam. Etiam consectetur pharetra libero, ut imperdiet quam semper ornare. Quisque id enim ut risus sollicitudin pharetra sed non mi. Sed posuere efficitur velit, sed tincidunt nisi ultricies ut. Sed neque ligula, cursus sit amet ipsum non, rutrum aliquet mi.
</p>
<p>
Mauris commodo malesuada arcu, eget rutrum nisl vulputate id. Nullam tristique consequat ornare. Donec sed nisi sit amet massa interdum blandit at sed erat. Nulla nunc lorem, porttitor sed luctus tempus, imperdiet et justo. Quisque rutrum massa in nisl eleifend, nec gravida ipsum sodales. Proin cursus nulla vitae nisl consectetur blandit. Ut eu mattis nibh, et egestas nunc. Ut tellus mi, scelerisque vel odio sit amet, molestie consequat mi. Praesent tristique fermentum arcu, in convallis sapien consequat id. Curabitur dui nisi, tincidunt sit amet rutrum non, pulvinar sed elit. Sed convallis cursus diam vel tincidunt. Vivamus fermentum magna blandit viverra suscipit. Aenean posuere nunc sed urna ullamcorper imperdiet. Donec viverra, felis id facilisis aliquet, metus ante rhoncus nisl, nec accumsan ante ipsum id mi. Aliquam erat volutpat.
</p>
<p>
Maecenas blandit luctus nisi eu gravida. Morbi at mi ac nibh semper tincidunt. Maecenas non urna ornare, tincidunt augue rhoncus, ultrices turpis. Praesent vitae scelerisque orci. Etiam hendrerit porta mauris venenatis egestas. Sed non purus laoreet, aliquet ex sed, laoreet quam. Etiam bibendum, ante ut tincidunt tincidunt, mauris tellus ultricies odio, porttitor cursus turpis dolor quis augue.
</p>
<p>
Nam tincidunt ut turpis nec pharetra. Suspendisse fermentum neque sit amet nulla facilisis, feugiat finibus magna scelerisque. Cras ut lacus varius, ultricies nulla sit amet, tempus nisi. Phasellus a condimentum ante. Quisque id nunc sed risus dapibus ullamcorper eget vel mi. Cras non maximus mauris. Proin ac nisl at ex vulputate ornare. Nullam sit amet faucibus nisl, ac dapibus tellus.
</p>
<p>
Vestibulum accumsan ultricies ex nec ullamcorper. Sed eget nisi varius, aliquam lorem non, mollis felis. Ut dolor augue, mattis ac arcu sed, elementum egestas lacus. Praesent quam nisi, egestas eget nisl vitae, dapibus mattis quam. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nulla cursus tempor ante, ac mollis massa. Cras congue ipsum et massa volutpat euismod. Sed eros orci, molestie vitae elit pretium, sagittis lacinia justo. Mauris egestas erat a arcu bibendum fermentum. Donec bibendum vitae dolor ut sodales. Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras sit amet lectus nec ligula viverra venenatis sed id lectus.
</p>
<p>
Mauris facilisis enim id magna sagittis laoreet. Quisque in tristique purus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Fusce dictum orci gravida ante fringilla, eu congue odio laoreet. Nam feugiat ante sit amet nisi bibendum, eget tincidunt nulla aliquam. Proin lorem nisl, egestas et fermentum at, elementum ac dui. Integer non varius sem. Aliquam quis rhoncus est, ut viverra lorem. Nunc ut ipsum sed arcu bibendum gravida porta id turpis. Fusce bibendum nisi orci, et faucibus justo ornare venenatis. Donec feugiat ante nec lacus dapibus, eu semper neque convallis. Sed sit amet eros ut tortor ultrices efficitur a a risus. Fusce varius dignissim tellus, at sodales augue faucibus id.
</p>
<p>
Mauris faucibus risus quam, ac facilisis massa laoreet nec. Duis consectetur, justo sit amet pulvinar pulvinar, orci eros venenatis felis, vitae rutrum diam lacus a arcu. Duis vitae tincidunt purus. Ut et felis nec quam bibendum vestibulum. Suspendisse tempor venenatis elit nec viverra. Morbi quis lectus nisi. Suspendisse nec pharetra odio.
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. I did not know about the order style setting. This is my first website. I'll try this out.